# Nodes and (edges label) are not responsive in small screen

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I try this code to representing networks graph for hotels. This codes output work well for large screen. But for small screen the code output not responsive, The nodes are cutoff and one node overlap another nodes. Another problem is edge label are also not responsive for small screen, edges label are overlap the nodes. Please suggest me how I solve this problem?

```
library(tidygraph)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)

# Create nodes
nodes <- tibble(id = 1:10, label = c("Hotel A bla  bla bla", "Hotel B bla  bla bla", "Hotel C bla  bla bla", "Hotel D bla  bla bla", "Hotel E bla  bla bla", "Hotel F bla  bla bla", "Hotel G bla  bla bla", "Hotel H bla  bla bla", "Hotel I bla  bla bla", "Hotel J bla  bla bla"))

# Specify edges
edges <- tibble(
  from = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  to = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  rating = c(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 9, 5, 3)  # Use 'rating' instead of 'label'
)

# Create a tidygraph
graph <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges)
prices <- c("Tk 1200", "Tk 1250", "Tk 1350", "Tk 1850", "Tk 1650", "Tk 2150", "Tk 1800", "Tk 2500", "Tk 1500", "Tk 1300")

# Add edge_size and layout
E(graph)$edge_size <- edges$rating
layout <- layout_with_kk(graph, weights = E(graph)$edge_size)

# Kamada-Kawai algorithm organizes nodes in a graph match the distances between them.
# Define the desired rating values
desired_ratings <- c("r-2.5", "r-3", "r-4", "r-6", "r-8", "r-7", "r-9", "r-5.5", "r-3")

# Plot the graph without legend
ggraph(graph, layout = layout) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(label = desired_ratings, vjust = 0.6, hjust = -0.7, color = "darkorange"), 
                 show.legend = FALSE,  # hide legend
                 start_cap = circle(5, "mm"),
                 end_cap = circle(5, "mm")) +
  geom_node_point(aes(color = as.factor(id)), size = 20) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = str_wrap(label, width = 12)), vjust = 0.2, hjust = 0.5, size = 2.5) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = prices), vjust = 2, hjust = 0.5, size = 3, color = "black") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, "cm"),
    legend.position = "none"  # hide legend
  )
```

[But this codes output not response in small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/722jV.png)
[This is my expected output in small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ2Sc.png)